# Django TextField max_length validation for ModelForm

Tags: django, django-validation

Django does not respect the max_length attribute of TextField model field while validating a ModelForm.

So I define a LimitedTextField inherited from the models.TextField and added validation bits similar to models.CharField:

```
from django.core import validators

class LimitedTextField(models.TextField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LimitedTextField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.max_length = kwargs.get('max_length')
        if self.max_length:
            self.validators.append(validators.MaxLengthValidator(self.max_length))

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'max_length': self.max_length}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(LimitedTextField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

But this still has no affect on ModelForm validation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As of Django 1.2 this can be done by validators at model level, as explained here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/

```
from django.core.validators import MaxLengthValidator

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(200)])
```

Since Django 1.7, you can use `max_length` which is only enforced in client side. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField)

Comment: From django 1.7, yon can use `max_length` attribute in TextField

Answer (score 12):

You can enforce a max length for a TextField by defining a CharField with a Textarea widget like this:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    textfield = models.TextField()

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    textfield = forms.CharField(
        max_length = 50,
        widget = forms.Textarea
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyClass
        fields = ('textfield',)
```

Comment: but then i should repeat this for every text field that i want to limit. it would be much better if nothing other then specifying max_length is required.

Comment: Yes, specifying max_length in the model would be a little easier, but the solution I offered is the standard approach you will find in many django apps, and even within django itself (see django.contrib.comments). I have yet to see the custom TextField you are describing.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No need to import MaxLengthValidator from validators for Django 2.x

```
from django.db import models
class Comment(models.Model):
  comment = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: It's always better to add some explanation to the answer. ;)

Comment: From the doc: If you specify a max_length attribute, it will be reflected in the Textarea widget of the auto-generated form field. However it is NOT ENFORCED at the model or database level.