# django: model inheritance and validators in admin

Tags: django

I have an abstract model that is inherited by 2 children.  In the children, one is setting a validator.  When I run the code, I see both children having the validator.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
class myAbstract(models.Model):
    Intro         = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class child1(myAbstract):
    class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'child 1'

class child2(myAbstract):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(child2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        intro = self._meta.get_field('Intro')
        intro.validators.append(MaxLengthValidator(60))

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = 'child 2'
```

In the admin if I add a child1 and then add a child2 then the validator kicks in for child2 and limits the number of characters.  If I start with child2 then child2 doesn't get the validator.

Is this the expected behavior?  If there, what is the suggested way of coding this?  I thought about moving Intro to the child classes.

**Solved:**
As Alasdair pointed out the validators is a class variable therefore this is the expected behavior.

I tried moving the Intro field to the child but that didn't work.  I used this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209550/757955 that sets forms.CharField in the modelform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `validators` are not set per model instance. When you append the `MaxLengthValidator`, you are altering the `intro` field of the parent class.

I don't think there's an easy way around this. You could write a `clean()` method for each child model, and perform the validation there. However, I think that moving the `intro` field into the child classes is probably the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

I did not really expect this behaviour, but there is a lot of magic happenign in the background with models. I see 2 solutions:

1. Change the instance, not the class. _meta is an class variable, thus _meta.get_field will return class attributes. I would rather try to manipulate the instance fields like so

   def **init**(...):
       self.intro.validators.append(MaxLengthValidator(60))
2. If 1 does not work, or you do not like it, leave the models alone, i.e. do not add the validator, but add the [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators) to the form that you use for the models. There you have more flexibility and can do what you want.

Comment: Setting the validators in model forms is a good idea. However the first suggestion won't work, because `self.intro` is the value of the field, so doesn't have a `validators` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `clean_fields()` method to the child model with extra validators.

Helpers:

````py
from typing import Any, Callable, Collection, Optional
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

ValueValidator: TypeAlias = Callable[[Any], None]
FieldsValidatorsDict: TypeAlias = dict[str, list[ValueValidator]]


def run_validators_in_fields_validators_dict(
    model_instance: models.Model, validators_dict: FieldsValidatorsDict, exclude: list[str] = None
) -> None:
    """
    Run validators in fields-to-validators dict.

    Useful for adding extra validation to the fields in child model that came from the parent.
    (It's not possible to change `validators` of fields from base class)

    Example:

    ```
    class Animal(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(validators=[...])

    class Dog(Animal):
        _extra_fields_validators = {"name": [...]}

        def clean_fields(self, exclude = None):
            errors = {}
            try:
                run_validators_in_fields_validators_dict(self, self._extra_fields_validators, exclude)
            except ValidationError as e:
                errors = e.update_error_dict(errors)
            try:
                super().clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
            except ValidationError as e:
                errors = e.update_error_dict(errors)
            if errors:
                raise ValidationError(errors)
    ```
    """
    if exclude is None:
        exclude = []

    errors = {}
    for field_name, validators in validators_dict.items():
        if field_name in exclude:
            continue
        try:
            _run_validators_on_field(model_instance, field_name, validators)
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors[field_name] = e.error_list

    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)


def _run_validators_on_field(model_instance: models.Model, field_name: str, validators: list[ValueValidator]) -> None:
    field = model_instance.__class__._meta.get_field(field_name)
    raw_value = getattr(model_instance, field.attname)
    clean_value = field.to_python(raw_value)
    errors = []
    for validator in validators:
        try:
            validator(clean_value)
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors.extend(e.error_list)
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)

validate_str_no_underscore = RegexValidator(
    regex=r"^[^_]*\Z",
    message="Should not contain underscore",
)
````

Usage:

```py
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Dog(Animal):
    _extra_fields_validators: FieldsValidatorsDict = {"name": [validate_str_no_underscore]}

    def clean_fields(self, exclude: Optional[Collection[str]] = None) -> None:
        errors = {}
        try:
            run_validators_in_fields_validators_dict(self, self._extra_fields_validators, exclude)
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors = e.update_error_dict(errors)
        try:
            super().clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors = e.update_error_dict(errors)
        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(errors)
```